# ValueError: A different mode has already been set!

Tags: python

help me for solving this error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ sudo python ControlTemp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ControlTemp.py", line 17, in
disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST)
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_SSD1306/SSD1306.py", line 288, in __init__
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_SSD1306/SSD1306.py", line 85, in __init__
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py", line 418, in get_platform_gpio
File "build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py", line 172, in __init__
ValueError: A different mode has already been set!
```

Comment: Can we see `ControlTemp.py`? And please edit it in to your question, don't post it in the comments. And why are you still using Python 2? (Unless you remapped `python` to`python3`) Python 2 is dead and the newer versions of Python 3 have many new features...

Comment: I doubt every python 2 project in existence has been ported to python 3, would be one reason.  Adafruit stuff goes back as long as the pi has been around (**although that might be the problem**). `python` still defaults to python2 on Raspbian/RpiOS. Othmani, you are going to have to provide more context if you want help with this.  Or try the same thing using `python3` instead.